# ftp behaving differently between windows 7 and 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a batch file which contains the following line...

```
ftp < ftpcom.txt
```

The ftpcom.txt file contain something along the lines of...

```
open ftp.mysite.com
myusername
mypassword
cd public_html
cd subdirectory
mput afile.txt
y
quit
```

This has been working perfectly on my windows 10 PC for some time but I have been temporarily forced to switch to an old windows 7 PC and now it gets stuck at the password. I.e. I see that it has connected to ftp.mysite.com and has read my username and is now asking for the password (I see the text "Password:") but I see nothing after that. The DOS box is just stuck - as if it was waiting for someone to type in a password. Maybe there is some windows 7 feature whereby ftp refuses to accept a password form a file?

Obviously this might not be a windows 7 vs. 10 issue at all - maybe it just some incorrect configuration setting.

Comment: I use FTP with a list of commands on Windows 7 almost every day. What happens if you use the `-s` flag to pass the text file?

Comment: Tada! - yes that did it! - if you put it as an answer I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `cmd.exe` if you run `ftp /?` you get some help. Let's focus on one particular part of this help output.

```
-s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands;
                the commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
```